# How to do factor analysis when there are multiple data about one objective?

Tags: sas, factor-analysis

20 respondents -> 100 questionnaires(10 identical questions each) about 5 brands

each respondent -> 5 questionnaires(5 brands)

should I preprocess the data(ex. calculate mean base on brands, the new input has only 5 data: brand 1 to 5 data) or should I just do FA straightforward?

btw not asking about coding, just pure stat question.

Comment: Cross Validated may be a better place to ask this question. https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Got it! Thanks mate!

Comment: You could transform your data to make it wide, so you do have 100 variables for each respondent. However, with only 20 respondents you don't have enough power to test anything conclusively, descriptive statistics is all you should do with N=20. Unless this is being used to calculate the overall sample size, though that's a different question.

Comment: @Reeza the actual data is 6*18 -> brand*respondent which is even smaller...but I am wondering if I just do FA straightforward, is the result significative at all?

Comment: All the example I had encounter before is 1 to 1 situation(ex. 10 different student with their grades -> FA comes up with factors), none of them is like this(100 data but actually describe 10 student with their grades at different time)

Comment: So 18 respondents and 6 surveys? That's not informative at all. Is this brands or grades? Over brands, which are nominal variables compared to time is a very different use case. You can't use FA, but repeated analysis is possible for that type of data. Your N is still small though.

Comment: thanks mate! but i have to use FA after all it s an homework. i think i already know what should I do, just do FA straightforward and not preprocessing at all. thanks again!